# JavaScript access request body

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page acting as an api for someone else's website. My page will be called through a post request containing a json object in the request body, is it possible to access this object by pure JavaScript? I'm trying to avoid relying on a specific server side technology.

Comment: Nope.  Requests are handled server-side. Javascript is purely client-side. (at least in your case as described)

Answer (score 0):

No. JavaScript in the browser is executed on the client side. You'll need server-side code to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

## No.

By it's very nature, POST bodies are sent to the server. You can only access that content if the server then dumps that body into the HTML page prior to the JavaScript running.